# Codeigniter shows repetitive rows on multiple JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query in Codeigniter:

```
    $this->db->select('p.productionId, p.name, p.year, p.poster, p.description_nl, p.story_nl, p.castCrew_nl, p.description_en, p.story_en, p.castCrew_en, GROUP_CONCAT(g.galleryId,".",g.name_nl) AS name_nl, GROUP_CONCAT(g.galleryId,".",g.name_en) AS name_en, COUNT("gi.url") AS url')->from('productions p');
    $this->db->join('galleries g', 'g.productionId = p.productionId', 'left');
    $this->db->join('galleryImages gi', 'gi.galleryId = g.galleryId', 'left');
    $this->db->group_by('p.productionId');
    $this->db->order_by('p.name', 'ASC');
    $this->db->order_by('p.name, gi.galleryId', 'ASC');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

The output this delivers is that each g.name_nl and g.name_en is part of a production ID, and hence puts those with the correct ID in a PHP foreach.

However, in that same foreach I want to show a count of the amount of URLS belong with that same gallery, which joins with the

```
$this->db->join('galleryImages gi', 'gi.galleryId = g.galleryId', 'left');
```

line in the code.

The error this results in, is that it listsall name_nl's and name_en's, rather than that it groups than if there are multiple rows.

How do I correct this?

-- update --
Foreach

```
<?php foreach ($productions as $production) { ?>
  <h3><?php echo $production->name; ?> (<?php echo $production->year; ?>)</h3><br />
  echo $production->name_nl;
  echo $production->url;
} ?>
```

Which results in:
A
A
A
B
A

Rather than
A
B
5

Comment: Can you provide your `foreach` loop and a sample output?

Comment: How does the output of `$this->db->last_query()` look? The actual database query should help debug the issue.